# Put retrofit object to other activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, retrofit

As I mentioned in the title, I am trying to send an object named "service" that I use in MainActivity to OtherActivity, but I was not successful.

Constant.kt

```
class Constants {

companion object{
    const val BASE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/customer/"
}
}
```

RetrofitInstance.kt

```
object RetrofitInstance {

private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null



fun getClient(username: String, password : String): Retrofit {

    val client =  OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(BasicAuthInterceptor(username,password))
        .build()



    val gson = GsonBuilder().apply {
        setLenient()
        registerTypeAdapter(Date::class.java,
                JsonDeserializer<Date> { json, typeOfT, context ->
                    if(json.asJsonPrimitive.isNumber) {
                        Date(json.asJsonPrimitive.asLong * 1000)
                    } else {
                        null
                    }
                })
    }.create()


    if (retrofit == null)
        retrofit =  Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()

    return retrofit as Retrofit
}
}
```

SimpleApi.kt

```
interface SimpleApi : Serializable{

@GET("list")
fun productList(): Call<MutableList<Product>>

@GET("api/data")
fun test(@Header("Authorization") autHeader: String): Call<String>


@GET("testc")
fun testCustomer(): Call<String>


@GET("cars")
fun getCars(): Call<List<Car>>

}
```

Create "service" in MainActivity.kt

```
    val service = RetrofitInstance.getClient(username,password).create(SimpleApi::class.java)
```

Create "Intent" in MainActivity.kt

```
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,OtherActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("service", service as Serializable)
                startActivity(intent)
```

Get "intent" in OtherActivity.kt

```
val service = (intent.getSerializableExtra("service") as? SimpleApi)!!
```

Comment: why you put service on an intent? AFAIK your object retrofit can called on other activity without it

Comment: Why you need the send retrofit to other activity? You can simply get retrofit from RetrofitInstance class.

Comment: I thought it was not correct to do it again because I provided authentication in the mainactivity. Or should I send the username and password to the Otheractivity?

Comment: You can create one function for create instance and use same `SimpleApi` everywhere you need

Comment: Wouldn't it be more costly to create an object in each activity than to send the object I created in mainactivity with intent? @mehmetsalimayan

Comment: I didn't said that. You need to create one instance and use it everywhere let me wrote that code for you.

Comment: oh sory :) You don't need to send anything. already said "service" is running in otheractiviy :) @mehmetsalimayan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `RetrofitInstance` like below

```
object RetrofitInstance {

    private var api: SimpleApi? = null


    fun createInstance(username: String, password: String): SimpleApi {
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(BasicAuthInterceptor(username, password))
                .build()


        val gson = GsonBuilder().apply {
            setLenient()
            registerTypeAdapter(Date::class.java,
                    JsonDeserializer<Date> { json, typeOfT, context ->
                        if (json.asJsonPrimitive.isNumber) {
                            Date(json.asJsonPrimitive.asLong * 1000)
                        } else {
                            null
                        }
                    })
        }.create()


        if (api == null)
            api = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build()
                    .create(SimpleApi::class.java)

        return api
    }

    fun getInstance() : SimpleApi {
        return api!!
    }
}
```

on your `MainActivity` call `createInstace` function to create your api instance. Other activities can call `RetrofitInstance.getInstance()` to get api.